# button in tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitableview

I have a button on a tableview cell. 
When its pressed, at the moment all I want is to add a different image. 
When its already in the function its already been pressed, so assigning an control event must be wrong. This **doesn't work** :

```
@IBAction func HeartPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    var heartImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "HeartPink.png")!
    sender.setImage(heartImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)

}
```

Any idea how to get an image set on a button in a tableviewcell ?

Comment: Do you only need to show the different image _while_ the button is pressed, or should the different image remain afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

It happen because button is overload one by one and in cell always last cell button change effect that you doing .. 
so please do in this minor change in this function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

in this function set button tag of all ..

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

and try again ..